# Monotouch and native iOS code

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to link a C# library compiled using monotouch with an objective-C front end in a single application, or does the app have to be all or nothing?

Comment: I am not sure about monotouch but I think if monotouch compiled it already, the iOS can run the code. I am not sure how you can call the C# library with the API but I think the linking is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but you aren't going to get any help from the MonoTouch tooling and you can't get away from the fact that you still have to have the Mono runtime to execute your C# code.

In order to provide the Mono runtime to the Objective-C app, the runtime will have to be embedded into the app.  The MonoTouch site has some docs on how to do this [here](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/XCode) and you can find more technical details about embedding Mono into your application [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono).

MonoTouch, when compiling your C# code, produces .m and .s files that are used by Objective-C to call that code.  These files will need to be included in the consuming Objective-C project but MonoTouch cleans up those files after they've been used.  In order to keep mtouch, the MonoTouch compiler, from deleting the .m and .s files, use the --keeptemp option when invoking the compiler.  You can find a good [sample Makefile here](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/monotouch-samples/blob/master/Make.common) to help you figure out how to call mtouch correctly from the command line.

Finally, you will need the full version of MonoTouch in order to do this.  The trial version will not generate the .s files.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It's disappointing that the trial version doesn't have the support needed to test this; but the library's large enough that it'd still probably be cheaper than a port.

Comment: As a followup, would the trial version allow compiling the library and running a dummy/proof of concept app to see if it will work?

Comment: Not exactly sure what is different with the proof of concept vs. what you initially described so I can't speak to that. Since you're asking about calling into MT code from ObjC I assume you have the source of the ObjC. You realize you can create bindings for your ObjC code and call into that code from MonoTouch. Trying to call MT from ObjC is like swimming against the current, possible but very tiring and difficult. I'd recommend looking at binding your ObjC code and invoke that from your MT app.  Here is more info on binding http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types

Comment: I don't have any ObjC code at present.  What I have is a C# windows app.  It's GUI/DAL components would to be replaced, but if possible I'd like to avoid having to spend a month or six porting the calculation library to ObjC.  My interest in calling an MT library from ObjC is trying to minimize the training cost by wrapping the C# code up as much as possible and having a coworker who does iOS apps write the UI.  If I end up writing the entire app 100% MT is more likely since I know C# well, but don't know ObjC at all.