# Is it possible to reference native code from a monotouch C# library?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to refactor some of the code of my monotouch app into a library (so I can use it in another app). Some of the code I want to move into the library is native (google analytics and facebook api native libraries), but I can't seem to find a way to get this to work, as you cannot link native code to monotouch libraries.

ie, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[iPhoneApp facebookLib.a facebookWrapper.dll] ->
[iPhoneApp] [SharedLibrary facebookLib.a facebookWrapper.dll]

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible, but perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Linking_Native_Libraries

and here

[Monotouch and native iOS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632613/monotouch-and-native-ios-code)

Comment: That describes my current state: an executable that links native code. What I want to do is have an executable that links a monotouch assembly (that will be shared between executables) that uses native code